# Permanently downcast a generic in a derived class

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, abstract-class

Ok so the scenario is I have several services that share similar behaviors and all contain settings that are shared across them.

These services have their own extended service specific settings which I am unable to access in the derived service class. Below is essentially an example of what I am trying to do.

```c#
public abstract class BaseSettings<T> where T : ISettings
{
  public string BaseSetting { get; } = "Hello from BaseSettings";
  // other settings, etc.

  public BaseSettings<T>() {}
}

public abstract class BaseService<T> where T : ISettings
{
  public BaseSettings<T> Settings { get; }

  public BaseService(BaseSettings<T> settings)
  {
    Settings = settings;
    Console.WriteLine(Settings.BaseSetting);
  }
}

public class ServiceASettings : BaseSettings<ServiceASettings>, ISettings
{
  public string SettingA { get; } = "Hello from SettingsA";

  public ServiceASettings() {}
}

public class ServiceA : BaseService<ServiceASettings>, IService
{
  public ServiceA(ServiceASettings settings) : base(settings) 
  {
   Console.WriteLine(Settings.SettingA); // cant see this property
   Console.WriteLine((Settings as SettingsA).SettingA); // prints fine
  }
}

// ServiceB, ServiceBSettings; ServiceC, ServiceCSettings; etc...

public class Program
{
  public static void Main(string[] args)
  {
    SettingsA settings = new SettingsA();
    ServiceA service = new ServiceA(settings);
    // does not compile because says there is no definition for 
    // Settings.SettingA within ServiceA
  }
}
```

I cannot figure out how to dynamically downcast(?) the Settings in the derived Service class to access them or essentially make them the appropriate concrete class.

Is there a way to permanently set Settings as the appropriate derived class or do I have to call the specific properties using casting on everything?

ie avoid `(Settings as SettingsA).PropertyA; (Settings as SettingsB).PropertyB` and so on?

Would appreciate if someone can explain how to accomplish this or if there is an easier way since may be over complicating this.

Any help is appreciated.

## Solution

changes made to get it to work

```c#
public abstract class BaseSettings
{
  public string BaseSetting { get; } = "Hello from BaseSettings";
  // other settings, etc.

  public BaseSettings() {}
}

public abstract class BaseService<T> where T : ISettings
{
  public T Settings { get; }

  public BaseService(T settings)
  {
    Settings = settings;
    Console.WriteLine(Settings.BaseSetting);
  }
}

public class ServiceASettings : BaseSettings, ISettings
{
  public string SettingA { get; } = "Hello from SettingsA";

  public ServiceASettings() {}
}
```

Thanks to Ann for the suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be the problem:

You have `BaseService.Settings` defined this way:

```
public abstract class BaseService<T> where T : ISettings
{
  public BaseSettings<T> Settings { get; }
}
```

It should probably be like this instead:

```
public abstract class BaseService<T> where T : ISettings
{
  public T Settings { get; }
}
```

The explanation: in your `ServiceA`, in the original implementation, your `Settings` property is going to be a `BaseSettings<ServiceASettings>`, not a `ServiceASettings`. And `BaseSettings<T>` never exposes a property of type `T`, so there's no way from within `ServiceA` to access a property of type `ServiceASettings`.

I don't think `BaseSettings` necessarily needs to take a generic type at all (based on what you've shown us), or if it does, that it needs to take another derivation of `ISettings` as its generic type, unless you're going to expose an instance of `T` from it.

There are a couple of other ways to approach the problem, as well.

Comment: Thanks @Ann -- I was heading down that route and read your answer and it cleared it up. I did see it kept referencing settings were of type BaseSettings<ServiceASettings> and I was trying to fix that and didnt think to put it as type T.

Comment: Glad it was cleared up!  I was coming back this morning to clarify my point, which was that you never actually exposed a `T`, so you can't access anything that's on `T`!